# Java API for parsing MapInfo TAB format

Tags: java, gis, geotools, mapinfo

I am working on parsing a MapInfo TAB Format file in Java. It consists of a set of four files viz .TAB, .ID, .MAP and .DAT. After searching on web I came across a parser provided by GeoTools at this repository: 
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/MapInfoFileReader.java

When I use this API for parsing the MAPInfo TAB format file bundle, the API throws exception:

> "Didn't find a minimum of three control points in the .tab file."

I am using public MapInfoFileReader(final File tabfile) constructor. I have tried using different versions of Geotools API.

Is there a work around for parsing MapInfo TAB Format file in Java? Or if anyone can provide sample code for using GeoTools' MapInfoFileReader

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a work around for parsing MapInfo TAB Format file in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to parse .TAB using java code. First of all you need to convert .TAB into KML or other extension using Gdal[1](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) or ogr2ogr using this command line tool

ogr2ogr -f "KML" "filepath/filename.kml" "filepath/filename.TAB"

After that you can parse .kml file using java code using DOM parser[2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b12024/oracle/xml/parser/v2/DOMParser.html) API available in java.

Comment: You would probably get better results using a ShapeFile as the intermediate step rather than KML as it will not require reprojecting your data to epsg:4326 and back again.

Answer (score 2):

The API you are trying to use is specifically for the use of raster tab files for the **GeoTiff** format. The title on the github page specifically mentions this:

> GEOT-4619: Support MapInfo TAB files in geotiff format reader

There is a C++ library available to read and write MapInfo TAB files called [MITAB](http://mitab.maptools.org/) which you could integrate into your application. Alternatively, you could use a library such as [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) to convert your data into MIF/MID (a plain text MapInfo file format) which you can then parse as text.