# How to read MID/MIF file using geoTools api

Tags: java, gis, geotools

Using the latest geotools version 19.1, I did not find any class which can read MID/MIF files. there was a MIFFile class in geotools version 2.2 which is removed now. 
Does anybody know how to read the the MID/MIF file format using geotools api in java ?

Comment: Check out http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/ there is support for TAB files. you might need to convert MID/MIF files to TAB format using GDAL.  SImilar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412305/java-api-for-parsing-mapinfo-tab-format

Answer (score 1):

Either convert your file to a supported format using `ogr2ogr` or try the experimental [OGR plugin](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/ogr.html).

If neither of those work for you, you can add or sponsor the addition of a dedicated Mid/Mif datastore.

Comment: were you able to succesfully run through the steps mentioned here [Build Instructions for GDAL/OGR In Java (Windows)](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructions) ?
I tried following the instruction but I am not able to proceed beyond  `nmake -f makefile.vc` step

Comment: use osgeo4w to download a compiled version

Comment: I did download the osgeo4w. but, on the page [Build Instructions for GDAL/OGR In Java (Windows)](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJavaBuildInstructions)
it is written
 _Note that ​OSGeo4W includes a ​gdal-java package and a Java runtime making it fairly easily to build local Java applications using GDAL._ 
but I did not find any gdal-java package or any jni library.

Comment: I'm not a windows user so I can't really help more

Comment: I was able to make it work. here is my answer [run gdal java on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50880821/1776145)